# Retrieve Japanese data from MS SQL Server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, character-encoding, odbc

I have some of the fields in the database(MS SQL Server) which at times have the Japanese data/characters as well. When I retrieve them using php, the data turn into ???? Such as I got a field Model which stores "BMW and JAPANESE CHARACTER" and when it comes to the page it turn into "BMW and ????????"

Below is my code;

```
     include ('org_dataDSN.php');
     //Setting up database virtual connection
    echo "Connecting Database <br>";
    header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); 
   echo "Successfully connected....";

    $subQuery="select model, make from infChnge_CS2002";
    $subRes=odbc_exec($connect, $subQuery);

    $ix=odbc_num_rows($subRes);
    echo "Success.." . $ix;
    while(odbc_fetch_row($subRes))
    {
$cstate = odbc_result($subRes, 1);
$sname = odbc_result($subRes, 2);

echo  $cstate . "<br>";
echo $sname . "";
    }

 odbc_close($connect);

      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First cast the data in the MSSQL query using cast function

```
SELECT CAST(model AS TEXT) as model, CAST(make AS TEXT) as make, FROM r_table;
```

In php, convert the casted data to utf-8:

```
$model = iconv('CP1255', 'UTF-8', $model);
$make  = iconv('CP1255', 'UTF-8', $make);
```

Answer (score -1):

i used this for mysql connection to correct ????? in Persian Language

```
    $connect=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connect);
```

query this "SET NAMES 'utf8'" right after creating connection to server

Comment: Boss I think you missed out, I am using MS SQL Server not mySql